# Is it possible to create structured documents in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I have a bunch of small books in my Google Drive. I would like to use Google API to format all of them through code. For that purpose, I need the documents to be structured. The idea is very simple. I need to be able to tag different paragraphs and headings.

It's possible in Google Docs to mark a paragraph as header, title, and subtitle. But I can't find an option to mark a paragraph as "quote" for example. Or mark a paragraph as "Formula".

Can I achieve that at all? Does Google Drive support HTML like tagging for extensible classification of a document structure?

Answer (score 1):

No, the structure of Google Documents is mostly presentational. See [the structure of a document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document) for an overview. The semantic markup is limited: the body of a document can contain

> ListItem, Paragraph, Table, and TableOfContents elements.

You can define  a special style for a quote, for example (like [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setAttributes(Object))):

```
 var quote = {};
 quote[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Verdana';
 quote[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 15;
```

and then use it throughout:

```
 var par = body.appendParagraph('A famous quote.');
 par.setAttributes(quote);
```

But as you can see, this is presentational, the choice being limited to the set of [attributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute) that a text element may have.

You can generate HTML with Google Apps Script using the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/), but this is really meant for serving HTML to web clients.

One reasonable option is to use a tool that generates Markdown. For example, [gdocs2md](https://github.com/mangini/gdocs2md) is an Apps script that produces Markdown from a Google Drive document. Of course, you will need to find something that can work with the type of the source documents you have now.

Comment: It may be possible to build something like this as an add-on using the [NamedRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range) class, but I'm not sure how usable it would be.